# How to align imagen inside a button JQM + HTML5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-mobile, uibutton

I have this issue of aligning an image with text inside a button. I've managed to do so, but this solution sets an image with text as part of the image instead. Then again if I had to change the text I would need to change the image text. Therefore it's somewhat useless.

As second solution, I've got an image inside the button besides a text which isn't aligned with my image. what could I do to make them fit?

`

Settings

Comment: Ary you asking about something as simple as formatting the image with `vertical-align:middle` …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new css class:

```
.my-button img
{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Next add this class to your a tag:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow my-button">
   <img alt="logo2" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png" height="40" width="40"/>Settings
</a>
```

Your code modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtorrescr/GRzn5/2/

Comment: Well, it didn't work 100% as I expected , but I'd say it's a 90%, because it fixed up the alignment. Thanks for answering Sir.

Comment: What is your expectation?